# ffmpeg cubemap to equirectangular

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So I saw a couple posts about converting cube map images into equirectangular, but couldn't find anything about video.

I have a cubemap video generated with facebooks transform filter for ffmpeg. I would like to change it back to equirectangular or spheric projection, but i can't find any ffmpeg filter capable of doing so.

Do I have to make my own filter? is there no ffmpeg solution for this?

Comment: Look into the [remap](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter) filter. You may need to create your own map files.